# jQuery tabs (how to hide loading MySQL tables?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using jQuery to show tabs and their contents; it works perfectly for text but takes time to print the results from MySQL tables (and when I refresh the web page, while it loads, it shows every tab's contents before getting back to normal).

Here is the jQuery script I put in the head area :

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($) {
        $('.tabs_up').each( function() {
            var container = $(this);
            container.find('> ul li a').click( function () {
                $(this).parent().addClass( 'selected-tab' ).siblings().removeClass( 'selected-tab' );
                container.find('.tab-panel').hide().filter(this.hash).show();
                return false;
            }).eq(0).click();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And the following HTML/ PHP code :

```
  <div id="tab-set-1" class="tabs_up">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-a" title="">Musique</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-b" title="">Dramas</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-1-a" class="tab-panel">
    <div class="largeur">
        <table class="liste tab_liste">
        <?php
        try
        {
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX', array (PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
                die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
        }
                $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT artiste, artiste_s, titre, titre_s FROM musiques WHERE moderation ="0" ORDER BY c_date_upload DESC LIMIT 5');
                $age = '';
                while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
                {                   
                    echo '<tr><td width="400px"><a href="'.append_sid('http://XXXXXXXXXX.com/chanson.php?artiste='.$donnees['artiste_s'].'&id='.$donnees['titre_s'].'').'">'.htmlspecialchars($donnees['artiste']).' - '.htmlspecialchars($donnees['titre']).'</a></td></tr>';
                }
                $reponse->closeCursor();
        ?>          
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tab-1-b" class="tab-panel">
    <div class="largeur">
        <table class="liste tab_liste">
        <?php
        try
        {
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX', array (PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
                die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
        }           
                $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT drama_nom, drama_nom_s FROM dramas WHERE moderation ="0" ORDER BY c_date_upload DESC LIMIT 5');
                $age = '';
                while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
                {                   
                    echo '<tr><td width="400px"><a href="'.append_sid('http://XXXXXXXXXX.com/serie.php?id='.$donnees['drama_nom_s'].'').'">'.htmlspecialchars($donnees['drama_nom']).'</a></td></tr>';
                }
                $reponse->closeCursor();
        ?>          
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I could hide the loading thing? Thank you

Comment: Why you connect every time to your database? You only need **one connection**. Why you use a very old jQuery Version?

Comment: You could hide the div on initial page load -> `<div id="tab-set-1" class="tabs_up" style="display:none;">` and then show it on page ready -> `jQuery( function($) { $('#tab-set-1').show(); ...`

Comment: I admit I could have used the newest jQuery version and limit the connections to my database to one, thank you for reminding me that. I updated it, it's faster but still shows the content of each tab during a fraction of seconds. What could I do to correct this?